# How to access a text file from anywhere in terminal

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I have two files. `file1` is executable and `file2` is just a text file and I use them frequently but I have to do `cd` every time to reach the directory.

How can I make `file1` universally executable in terminal and how to access the content of `file2` irrespective of my location in terminal.
Is it possible to add content of `file2` in `man page` so that I can just do `man file2`.

I think this can be done using `/etc/environment` but I want to know proper method of doing this.

Comment: you don't have to `cd`, you can just type the full path from anywhere, for example `less ~/mystuff/file2` and that can be made into an alias, or you can add `mystuff` to your path, etc, etc, as explained in linked post

Comment: @Zanna Thanks for the link. Trying those solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this using link provided by @Zanna.

For file1:

```
sudo ln -s /full/path/to/my/file1 /usr/local/bin/name_of_new_command
```

And for file2 I wrote a function in `~/.bashrc` file as,

```
file2 () {
 pwd=$PWD
 cd /full/path/to/my/file2_directory
 if [ "$1" == "more" ] || [ "$1" == "less" ]; then
    $1 file2
    cd $pwd
 else
    $1 file2 &
    cd $pwd
 fi 
}
```

This way I can open file2 in `less`, `more`, `gedit` or any other editor by passing extra argument like:

```
file2 less
file2 more
file2 gedit
```

Comment: Yes, a function is a good tool, particularly if the task is more advanced. For simple tasks, an alias might be more convenient.

Answer (score 3):

`PATH` environment variable is for this purpose. Add directories contain `file1` and `file2` to PATH, then you can access then by only the file name.

To add directory `/opt/myapp` to `PATH` environment variable use this:

```
PATH=/opt/myapp:"$PATH"
```

You can add above command to `~/.bashrc` for permanent change. Run `source .bashrc` to reload `.bashrc` for current terminal.

Another way is to make a soft link of `file1` and `files` to inside `/usr/bin` directory.

Answer (score 2):

You have the solution how to run an executable without typing the full path already. So I will suggest a solution to the second problem.

I guess that you have one or only a few special files, that you want to access directly. I suggest that you view them with **less** (which is also used for man pages). I also guess that your files have names different from executable programs. Otherwise you should rename them in order to avoid confusion. (For example, it is a bad idea to access a file called sudo with this method.)

You can create an **alias**, and store that alias in your file **~/.bashrc**

```
alias file2='less /path/to/file2'
```

where you replace /path/to/ with the actual directory path.

Run

```
file2
```

and check that it works. When it works you can add the alias command line into your ~/.bashrc file near the other aliases. Run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to get it active in already opened terminal windows. The next time you log in, it will be there for you to use.